# how to show category image and that category associated product in home page

Tags: magento2

I want show the category image and their product on  home page i used many example but none to work for me can any one help me to do this task thanks in advance.

Comment: Goto `catalog>manage Categories> select your Category`. Under Description `WYSIWYG Editor` click `Insert Image` insert your image.

Comment: If it is okay for you please update me

Comment: please read my post above this  is not my answer